# JNAerator BridJ runtime static methods instance memory

Tags: memory, static, jnaerator, bridj

So I've recently updated my JNAerator and started using the new BridJ runtime and I'm trying to debug a problem I'm having and I'm not sure if it is my library's code or JNAerator itself.

Basically in my C library I have an `init()` method that will initialize in memory shared variables across the other C library methods. I've noticed that with the new BridJ runtime and the new annotations that the Java code generated for my library creates only static methods. Would this cause problems with my C library maintaining in memory values across the different calls to the various static Java methods?

Answer (score 0):

In BridJ, bindings of C methods that are static or not static are strictly equivalent (although non-static binding methods obviously require you to instantiate your library class).